# Update a varchar with number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

In my table I have a `varchar` column that I want to updated with another data. The `varchar` column is like  this for example: `AB1600150`.

I am trying to update this column to decrease the number attached so the column data will be `AB1600149`.

I executed this code:

```
UPDATE [SONE].[dbo].[F_DOC] 
SET [DC_Piece] = 'FA' + MAX(RIGHT([DC_Piece], 7)) - 1   
WHERE [cbMarq] = 8
```

I got this error:

> it lacks an aggregate in the definition list of an UPDATE statement .

Please help me.

Comment: Datatype of `[DC_Piece]`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE  [SONE].[dbo].[F_DOC] 
SET   [DC_Piece] = 'FA' +  CAST (CAST(RIGHT([DC_Piece],7)AS INT)-1 AS VARCHAR)   
where  [cbMarq]=8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  [SONE].[dbo].[F_DOC] 
SET   [DC_Piece] = 'FA' +  RIGHT('0000000', 
                                    CAST(
                                    CAST(right([DC_Piece],7) as int) - 1  as varchar(7), 
                           7) 
WHERE [cbMarq]=8
```